# Is there any bonus to do all the bounties?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any bonus to do all the bounties in all the five acts ?

I know there is a bonus (more blood shards) for 2 acts, but if I do the three others is there some kind bonus to have done all the bounties ?

Comment: What do you mean by "2 bonus on 2 random acts"? You get a Horadrim Cache when you complete each Area, that is all I know of.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for being vague ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier in RotS beta completing all 25 bounties would reward you with Greater horadric cache.

[image]

Since then they decided to remove them from game,rewards they could contain are now droppable by Rift bosses.
[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12250204985).

So currently there is no bonus benefit from completing all 25 bounties.